# Why is the border box disappearing in Android Chrome?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, button

I have this button

```css
.btn-feedback {
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
}

.btn-feedback {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.45857;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"]{
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn-feedback">Skip</button>
```

Although everything looks normal on **Google Chrome for Mac**:

[image: Button as it appears on Mac Chrome]

when I view the same button on **Google Chrome on Android**, it appears to be missing the border ...

[image: Button as it appears on Android]

I'm unfamiliar with the rendering discrepancies between the two platforms.  Any thoughts on how I can modify my styles so that the button appears the same on Android Chrome as it does on Google Chrome on a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling for the button border is missing. If you do not explicitly state the border color styling, you will get the styling the device browser user agent gives you.

```css
.btn-feedback {
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
}

.btn-feedback {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.45857;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  /*Explicitly add a color for the border. I have also used shorthand for border style color and width*/
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"]{
  /*Add all the prefix versions for the different browser types*/
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
}

button, input, select, textarea {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn-feedback">Skip</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In WebKit (and Blink) engine, `<button>`s get the `-webkit-appearance:button;` default style.

[`-webkit-appearance:button`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_appearance) gives the buttons such look and feel (see below) and is **platform dependent**.

You can apply it to other elements:

```css
.webkit-appear-button { -webkit-appearance:button; }
```

```html
<button>I'm a button</button>

<span class="webkit-appear-button">I'm a span, but look like a button</span>
```

That's what's happening to your button. Since you don't specify a `background-color` it inherits from `-webkit-appearance:button`, which, as said, changes depending on the platform.

**Solution:** use `background-color: #color` (`background: #color` equivalent).